# Making a DataGridView column editable after binding it to a BindingList<T>

Tags: c#, binding, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a `DataGridView` and I'm binding it to a `BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, float>>`. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn firstColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        firstColumn.DataPropertyName = "Key";
        firstColumn.HeaderText = "First Column";

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn secondColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        secondColumn.DataPropertyName = "Value";
        secondColumn.HeaderText = "Second Column";
        secondColumn.ReadOnly = false;
        secondColumn.ValueType = typeof(float);

        dgv.Columns.Add(firstColumn);
        dgv.Columns.Add(secondColumn);
        dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgv.MultiSelect = false;
        dgv.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystrokeOrF2;
        dgv.ReadOnly = false;

        _bindingList = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, float>>(_someList);
        dgv.DataSource = _bindingList;
```

But the second column is still not editable. What should I do to make the second column editable and the first one not?

**Edit:** I'd like the changes to be reflected on the `BindingList` instance itself.

**Edit 2:** I have added this line in the end of the code and now I'm getting an error:

```
        dgv.Columns[1].ReadOnly = false;
```

I get this error:

`DataGridView column bound to a read-only field must have ReadOnly set to True.`

**Edit 3:** The problem seems to be that I'm using `KeyValuePair`s in my list.

Comment: At this point, does your BindingList have any data?

Comment: It does have data. I can see all the elements in the `BindingList`. But I cannot edit the second column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem turns out to be that the `Key` and `Value` properties of the `KeyValuePair` class are read-only. The solution is to create a new class that has `public setter`s to represent the data.